# Tmail ruby handler

Tags: ruby, tmail

how to specify the attachment name in Tmail .
i searched the documentation but couldnt get a clear idea . 
wen ever i send a mail wit an attachment i gives the attachment name as 'noname'

how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Use the `mail` gem instead. It's pretty [well documented](http://github.com/mikel/mail).